# Makefile line `test -f `

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a Makefile with the following line:

```
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
```

Can you explain me what this line does?

Note: The Makefile is taken from here: https://projects.coin-or.org/BuildTools/wiki/user-examples

That page specifies this:

> The generic compilation rules (e.g., .c.o) might look somewhat
>   complicated. But with this, the Makefile can also be used by people
>   who work with the MS compilers (e.g., cl) under Cygwin, since those
>   compilers don't understand the UNIX-type directory paths. In such a
>   case, the CYGPATH_W will have been set to "cygpath -w" by configure,
>   otherwise it is just "echo".

I am not going to work with MS compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `test -f` thing is a Unix-ism that will return true if the specified file exists and false if it does not. "$<" is the source file for a make rule. So `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'` will check for the existence of the source file and if it does **not** exist, will echo `$(SRCDIR)/` followed by the name of the file. That will be the input to the actual compiler.

It's basically saying "if file *X* exists in the local directory, then compile it. Otherwise (that's what the `||` does), compile the file called *X* located in the directory `$(SRCDIR)`". This way you can put all your source in a subdirectory and then override certain files by putting new copies of them in the same directory as the Makefile.

Comment: Okay, so let's suppose all the source files are located in the same directory the Makefile is, if I understand well I could replace the line by `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ '$<'`.

Comment: One more question: Are the ` 's necessary?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions. The backtick tells the shell "execute this command and then insert the result (i.e. stdout from the command) here."